# FOSUserBundle customise login process

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am currently using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony 3.4 based project.  We have some front-end design changes planned and I want to integrate the login form to the standard page template for non-logged in users to be able to login wherever they are on the app.

In my template file I am calling:
`{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}`.  This is correctly rendering the login form within the relevant pages.

However I have two problem I am unable to figure out how to overcome...

1. If the user enters invalid credentials, how can I return the user to the page they were on rather than the `/login` route?
2. How can I intercept the error message (Invalid credentials etc.)?  I would want to make it a flash message and then display it elsewhere in the master template.

Happy to provide further information if required.

t2t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an eventListener on 'onAuthenticationFailure'.
You will get the request and referer.

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case; you need to create custom Login page.

To do that;

1- Create your own `SecurityController.php`. Then copy 'loginAction' and 'renderLogin' method from the original SecurityController `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/SecurityController.php` paste into it and add `/login` path to loginAction.

2- Create your own `login.html.twig`. Then copy content of `login_content.html.twig` from `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/Security/login_content.html.twig` paste into your own.

3- Change return of renderLogin to your own `login.html.twig`

After these steps you can modify whatever you want. If you want to different route after wrong credentials then check the `$error` variable and make redirection.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I was meaning - I am already overriding these files and thatw as not the solution.